# Can't import ToTensorV2 in Colab

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

```
from albumentations.pytorch.transforms import ToTensorV2
```

I used the above code, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add a code block with the line

```
! pip install albumentations==0.4.6
```

above the block where you do the import. I tried installing it without the specific version and it failed.

When i did not specify the version number in pip install, version 0.1.12 was installed which does not contain ToTensorV2.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that you have the latest version

```
!pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-deps albumentations
```

Answer (score 0):

Get albumentations from Github.
[Usage on Colab Example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JuZ23u0C0gx93kV0oJ8Mq0B6CBYhPLXy#scrollTo=FxiIX49V_ZUQ&forceEdit=true&sandboxMode=true)

```
!pip install -U git+https://github.com/albu/albumentations > /dev/null
```