# Cannot fix ImportError: cannot import name 'ToTensorV2' from 'albumentations.pytorch' on Colab

Tags: pip, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I tried all three solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62872413/cant-import-totensorv2-in-colab) to solve the problem, but still receive an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ToTensorV2' from 'albumentations.pytorch' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/albumentations/pytorch/__init__.py)
```

My current code:

```
!pip install -U albumentations
import albumentations 
from albumentations.pytorch import ToTensorV2
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried factory resetting the runtime? If you haven't, maybe python was still loading the earlier version. I have just tested the accepted solution from the linked question on a fresh colab instance and it worked fine:

```
!pip install albumentations==0.4.6
import albumentations 
from albumentations.pytorch import ToTensorV2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, is should solve your issue:

```
from albumentations.pytorch.transforms import ToTensor, ToTensorV2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Here it works for me. Importing from github doesn't have any kind of problem.

`!pip install -U git+https://github.com/albu/albumentations > /dev/null && echo                 import albumentations                                                                             from albumentations.pytorch import ToTensorV2`